# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"` for v-file-input Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating a reusable component for `v-file-input` of Vuetify.

**Form.vue**

```html
<BaseFile v-model="image" label="Upload Image"/>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Form',
    data() {
      return {
        image: []
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**BaseFile.vue**

```html
<v-file-input
  :value="value"
  :label="label"
  solo
  show-size
  @change="updateValue">
</v-file-input>

<script>
 export default {
   name: 'BaseFile',
   props: {
     label: { type: String },
     value: { type: Array }
   },
   methods: {
     updateValue(file) {
       if (file.name) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = e => {
            const base64Data = e.target.result;
            const uploadFile = [{ fileName: file.name, base64: base64Data }];

            this.$emit('input', uploadFile);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       }
     }
   }
 }
</script>
```

The image value becomes

```js
[ 
  { fileName: 'hello.png', base64: '.....'}
]
```

But I'm getting a

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: The problem that your version calls change event 3 times. `v-file-input` have `truncateText` function, which accepts `str`. Your component provides it only for first call, and for second 2 it raise error, coz try to get length of undefined.

Comment: How come it calls change event 3 times? I can see that the `image` becomes the array of object

Comment: if extend inner `v-file-input` methods, you'll see that your `BaseFile` tries to truncateText multiply times, but provides string for it only once/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is `v-file-input` expects `value` prop to be "A single or array of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects." so as soon as you pick one file, content of `image` data (and consequently `value` prop) will become something different than Vuetify expects...

Comment: Is there a way that I can still use `v-file-input` in this case? I need to have `fileName` and `base64` in an Object so I can pass it to the backend API to upload.

Comment: Of course you can use `v-file-input`, just don't try to put your own objects into it's `value` prop.